# Error in my Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I keep receiving error whenever I run the code, If anyone could explain what is wrong or show me a fixed version? I would be very grateful

Mixed Content:

> The page at 'https://www.roblox.com/catalog/' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://c3.rbxcdn.com/4b192cd410398472f25d7aea541a352c'. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

*Code:*

```
var globeid = 0
var priceUnder = 5000


function check(z){
$.get(z, function(data){
          if ($(data).find('#ctl00_cphRoblox_LimitedEditionRemaining').length) {
                var check = $(data).find('#BuyWithRobux').children('div').data()
                var Token = data.match(/Roblox.XsrfToken.setToken([^)]+)/)[1].match(/[^(']+/)[0]
                if (check['expectedPrice'] <= priceUnder) {
                    $.post('https://www.roblox.com/api/item.ashx?rqtype=purchase&productID=' + check["productId"] + '&expectedCurrency=1&expectedPrice=' + check["expectedPrice"] + '&expectedSellerID=1')
                    console.log('Purchased: ' + check["itemName"] + " | " + check["itemId"] + " for " + check["expectedPrice"])
                }
          }
})
}

function checkifnewlim() {
    $.get("https://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=261522650").success(function(r) {
        r = decodeURIComponent(r);
        r = JSON.parse(r.substring(r.indexOf("{"), r.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
        var notifications = r
        for (var info in notifications) {
            var currid = notifications[info]["id"]
            if (currid > globeid) {
                console.log("NEW ITEM...")
                globeid = currid
                notificationpopup(notifications[info])
                var nn = notifications[info]
                var url = nn.url.split('&')[0]
                check(url)
            }
        }
    })

    function notificationpopup(n) {

        var notification = new Notification(n.lite, {
            icon: n.icon,
            body: n.header + "\n" + "Price: " + n.items.Price + "\n\n" + "Autobuy: OFF"
        });
var url = n.url.split('&')[0]
        notification.onclick = function() {
            console.log("NOTIFICATION SUCCESS!");
            window.open(url);
        }
    }
}
setInterval(function() {
    checkifnewlim()
}, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code runs on an HTTPS page, you can only request HTTPS content from other domains, any xhr requests that try to talk to HTTP resources will be blocked by the browser. If the content you're trying to reach is on your domain, make sure it's served over HTTPS. Otherwise you can do one of two things:

- If you have some server-side code running, you can try to add a hook that will proxy the call for you.
- People have tried to solve this issue by using third party libraries like [this one here](https://github.com/atmos/camo), which hides that complexity from you.